# Is it possible to show thumbnails along with recent post from a wordpress blog on static website's homepage?

Tags: post-thumbnails, recent-posts

Please help me to figure this out that I want to show **thumbnails along with recent post from a wordpress blog on static website's homepage**.

Following code are working fine but I need to show one single image from post as thumbnail:

> ```
> <?php
> define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
> require('blog/wp-blog-header.php');
> ?>
>
> <?php
> $args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date");
> $postslist = get_posts( $args );
> foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post);?>
>
> // Here I want to show post's thumbnail
>
> <h4 class="post-modern-title">
>   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
> </h4>
> <p class="post-short-info">
>
> // Here I want to show post's short info
>
> </p>
> <?php endforeach; ?>
> ```

**Right now it is showing like this :-**

> [image]

**But I want to show like this :-**

[image]

**Here are the updated code :-**

```
<?php
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
    require('blog/wp-blog-header.php');
    ?>
     <div class="row row-60 row-sm">
       <?php
       $args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date");
       $postslist = get_posts( $args );
       foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post);?>
       <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 wow fadeInLeft">
         <!-- Post Modern-->
         <article class="post post-modern"><a class="post-modern-figure" href="<?php the_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>" target="_top">
           <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ); ?>
             <div class="post-modern-time">
               <!-- <time datetime=""><span class="post-modern-time-month">07</span><span class="post-modern-time-number">04</span></time> -->
               <time datetime=""><span class="post-modern-time-number"><?php echo the_date( 'd/m' ); ?></span></time>
             </div></a>
           <h4 class="post-modern-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>" target="_top"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
           <p class="post-modern-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
         </article>
       </div>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
     </div>
```

**I'm getting following output where I'm unable to see date in a single post:-**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer below

```
<?php
        define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
        require('blog/wp-blog-header.php');
        ?>
         <div class="row row-60 row-sm">
           <?php
           $args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date");
           $postslist = get_posts( $args );
           foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post);?>
           <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 wow fadeInLeft">
             <!-- Post Modern-->
             <article class="post post-modern"><a class="post-modern-figure" href="<?php the_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>" target="_top">
               <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ); ?>
                 <div class="post-modern-time">
                   <!-- <time datetime=""><span class="post-modern-time-month">07</span><span class="post-modern-time-number">04</span></time> -->
                   <time datetime=""><span class="post-modern-time-number"><?php echo get_the_date( 'd/m', $post->ID ); ?></span></time>
                 </div></a>
               <h4 class="post-modern-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>" target="_top"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
               <p class="post-modern-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
             </article>
           </div>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
         </div>
```

Please try and let me know if any query.

Comment: Thanks buddy for all your help and support.... much appreciated :)

Comment: Here I implemented this with my codeigniter  project : ecommercecoach.in

Answer (score 0):

Use **get_the_post_thumbnail** function for get post featured image like

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID );
```

And for small content use **the_excerpt** function like

```
the_excerpt();
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Thanks @pratik-patel buddy for all your help

Comment: Also I'm using '<?php the_date(); ?>' in the loop but it is showing only in one post instead of all post. Do you have any idea, please help?

Comment: Can you please show me your code what you did so far?

Comment: Please check above where I updated the all code's screenshot in last of the post.

Comment: @Pawan I have added another answer below for **Date** so please check and let me know if you have any query.Thanks!